# Why node app is consuming more ram usage even the heap memory is low?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, memory-management, nodejs-server

I have deployed a NodeJS application in Linux machine with 8GB ram, while doing load testing node application is consuming Linux memory up to 95% and machine gets crashed and requires rebooting the system. I have checked the heap memory which is about to 30mb. So, I can't understand why the memory usage is increasing and what kind of data is consumed?

Used the following to command to check the live memory usage,

`top -o %MEM%`

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a memory leak in your code somewhere. One that is possibly handled/suppressed in your development environment but is not in Linux.

Some suggestions to get you on the right track:

- Check that any streams are closed properly.
- Ensure growing arrays are limited to reasonable max length.

Comment: But i have tried the ways removing logging mechanism and also remaining items are external service call. Is there a way to figure it out like package, tool??

Comment: The built-in process module has a method memoryUsage that offers insight in the memory usage of the current Node.js process. You could measure usage of certain methods/functions by taking measurements before after expensive operations. 

I'm not aware of any tools otherwise that are currently maintained otherwise, only dead one.

Comment: @YourNameHere unfortunately that's not working properly. I've got simple proxy app done in Node.JS. While passing down big files Node.JS JavaScript Runtime process grows to sizes like 2GB, while process.memoryUsage() reports usages of like 37MB, inspector snapshots shows 44.5MB heap size. So clearly something's off.

Answer (score 0):

if its a web app then consider writing in go. It has a much efficient garbage collection and is battle tested, however if you're keen on developing in js then consider switching to bun. It's fast and has a efficient memory management than node. Hope this helps